# How to merge TopoJSON features?

Tags: qgis, geojson, topojson

I currently have a coordinate based map of the US and it's states for topojson (https://github.com/mbostock/topojson).

The coordinates are a JSON array (as topojson works), data looks like this:

```
[-123.233256,42.006186], [-122.378853,42.011663]...
```

Now what I'd like to do is combine states into regions, outside of doing this by hand (and that idea makes me feel sick), are there any tools which I can use to accomplish this?

I have QGIS but have no clue where to even start (let alone how to combine states in QGIS).

Comment: So it sounds like you are trying to ["merge features"](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/merging-polygons-in-qgis.html), but with a source topojson file, correct?

Comment: Correct! I can do this in inkscape with the SVG, but obviously that is post-projection. :( I'm assuming I may have to get the original maps for QGIS and do it there? I can't seem to go from topojson > QGIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use topojson.merge to do this, as shown in [bl.ocks.org/5416405](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416405):

[image: merging states]

There are a few limitations to this approach (such as its dependence on an exact topology and lack of detection of holes), but it might for you as-is or with a few adjustments.

There is also the simpler approach of drawing the set of polygons for each region twice, once with a stroke and once with a fill, as shown in [bl.ocks.org/5416440](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416440):

[image: merging states ii]

See also a [very similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092564/d3-merge-interior-svg-paths).

Comment: Awesome, got this implemented in very little amount of time. Thanks and works fine without adjustments. Guess I need to dig at topojson's docs more, it's quite powerful.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that, for the moment, QGIS does not recognize the TopoJSON format (too recent). The solution is to transform the TopoJSON file into GeoJSON format:

- online [GeoJSON - TopoJSON](http://jeffpaine.github.io/geojson-topojson/) conversion
- in Python Sean Gillies [TopoJSON with Python](http://sgillies.net/blog/1159/topojson-with-python/)  and Calving Metcalf [topojson.py](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/topojson.py)

and you can import the GeoJSON file in QGIS