# Merging separate country features together into one region

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, topojson

I am trying to creating a map of the UK where Scotland and England are merged into one shape and not separate shapes for each country. As a minimum working example, I'm following Mike Bostock's [Let's Make a Map tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Is it possible to use GDAL to merge geographic features together into one contiguous feature?

How can I combine countries together into one shape/region which I can use to display in a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by using GDAL following [this discussion on GDAL-dev mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Dissolve-shapefile-using-GDAL-OGR-tp5036930p5036973.html).

As stated in the mentioned topic, you need GDAL compiled with Spatialite support.

[An alternative](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71327/how-to-merge-topojson-features) is already provided on the forum at TopoJSON level by @mbostock